# How to create a sketch area in a ui window

Tags: qt, layout, qt5, qlayout

My requirement.

[image]

What I tried in Qt 5.15?

[image]

My Question: How to create sketch area in the layout window so that there is sketching space and space for my sketching features?
Can anyone help with this? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Are you want to add a splitter in future or not?

Answer (score 1):

you need to play with the layout properties... specifically the [layoutstretch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

if you set that to 1,5 the left widget is taking space in a ration 1:5 to the right widget...

Answer (score 0):

1.First of all, I put all your TabWidget in centralwidget with 2 tabs Tab1 and Tab2 like this :

[image]

2. I go to this and change the maximum size to 200 this is l1.

[image]

3.set GridLayout For centralwidget and add one widget near Tabwidget.

[image]

**you can set maximum width of widget to 1000.as l1*5.**

4.put pushbuttons in tab1 and I set Vertical layout for Tab1 .

[image]

this UI code you can copy+past it in your UI file and use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>537</width>
    <height>357</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>200</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>200</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 1</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton 1</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton 2</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton 3</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton 4</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton 5</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton 6</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 2</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>1000</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>1000</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>537</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuEdit">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Edit </string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuAbout">
    <property name="title">
     <string>About</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuEdit"/>
   <addaction name="menuAbout"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```